# Calculate Price with date range

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker

So, I am developing a web based application for an airport parking. I am using Twitter bootstrap for the form. To get the date and time range of every enquiry I am using [Date Range Picker for Bootstrap](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). What I would like to do is to dynamically change a label's value called "Total Price" which is found in the [booking page](http://a2ltd.gr/appt/auto/auto.html) based on the Date Range Picker's inputs (located on the top). Browsing their documentation I could not find something similar to my case. The charging rates are 0.01 per hour. For example: In case I am in the process of my enquiry and I choose to drop my car off at Saturday 10 (00:00) and pick it up at Sunday 11 (00:00) the price label should display "24€".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: Hello manetsus and thanks for commenting. It is my understanding that I have nothing to show but I am really stuck at this point.

Comment: If the charge rate is 0.01 per hour, shouldn't 24 hours cost €0.24?